# Win32 popup menu width

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, popupwindow

C++ / Win32.
As shown in the popup menu pic, there's a large space at the right side of the menu. This is common to all popup menu's I've seen, probably there as a placeholder for a shortcut key combination.
I was asked to clip the width to the menu text, but couldn't find any way to do it using the standard menu API or window repositioning API.

Is there any simple method to do it without going into owner-drawn?

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, (popup) menu layout is built into the system, and you have no way to adjust the geometry of a menu, without [creating owner-drawn menu items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items). See also this Q&A: [Setting the width of a menu in the Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518910/1889329).

Comment: You could in theory retrieve the window handle of the popup menu as documented in the remarks of the [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) function: `FindWindowEx( NULL, NULL, MAKEINTATOM(0x8000), NULL );` and call `SetWindowPos()` to set the desired size. The reliability of this method is questionable though.